# Block a function and resume when I return on app

Tags: angularjs, gps

I'm using ionic with angularjs to develop an app. In this app I use cordova geolocation to get my position and if my gps is disable, the app open the device settings.

This is the code:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

    var geocoder;
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  $scope.initialise = function() {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout : 5000, maximumAge : 0}); 
    function onSuccess(position){

      alert("success")
    }
    function onError(error){
      alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
               cordova.plugins.settings.openSetting("open", function(){console.log("opened settings")},function(){console.log("failed to open nfc settings")});

    }

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialise());
```

});

When settings are open and I enable gps, I would like that when I press back button, the function initialise restart.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can use state.go to redirect app to your init page

Comment: can you write an answer with an example?

Comment: Two questions: do you use stateProvider and what is your main page?

Comment: I read [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) docs but I don't understand so good how it works. When app enter in errorCallback, shows me an alert and when I press ok, app runs  cordova.plugins.settings.openSetting that open settings device. So, when I press back button and I return to my app, I would like that function initialise restart again.

Comment: with main page you meaning my HTML page?